# Accessing a MinWindow function from another function outside MainWindow Qt

Tags: c++, qt, function, mainwindow

I have a Qt gui project and in the "mainwindow.cpp" file I have to define a function that I cannot declare under "mainwindow.h". But I want to call that function (func_sqrt) under MainWindow and show the result value of my func_sqrt in a label. For some reason I need to do that so. But I don't know how to connect that function to the gui objects. My code looks like this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

QString input;

void func_sqrt(int x);

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    func_sqrt(2);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::showtext(QString txt)
{
    ui->lbl_value->setText(txt);
}

void func_sqrt(int x)
{
    int y;
    y = x*x;
}
```

I added this part to the func_sqrt function, but it doesn't work:

```
MainWindow *w = new MainWindow;
w->showtext(QString::number(y));
```

Comment: `that I cannot declare under...` Why???

Comment: what is `y`, is member of `MainWindow`?

Comment: `MainWindow *w = new MainWindow;` do you really want to create a new main window? Usually you create the main window 1 time in main().

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your func_sqrt currently is a no-op. Next, internally it calculates a square yet its name says sqrt (short for square root), you might want to check whether the name is consistent with semantics. This is for the side notes.

If you need this function available outside of mainwindow.cpp, you can declare it in a separate header and include it everywhere as needed. Alternatively, you can declare it in every file it is used in, the linker will later resolve the actual implementation. For instance, in a file subordinatewindow.cpp:

```
void func_sqrt(int);

// ...

int x{42};
func_sqrt(x);
```

Comment: Yes, that is true. my code is actually different, but because it was too much, I made very quick sample representing the same problem as my code. So the names do not matter.
But with your answer I am not sure if my code will work, if I define the function in another header. I think it might be better to shortly explain what I want to do in my main code:

Comment: I have a CallBack function which will be called during the main code. This function is of type static void and when I tried to declare it under "mainwindow.h" as a static void and define it again in "mainwindow.cpp" as a static void, it didn't work, so I decided not to put in under "mainwindow.h".  But again I changed something and in "mainwindow.h" I defined it as static void, but in the "mainwindow.cpp" I should write it as "void MainWindow::myfunc()" not static void! I don't know how to solve it. I thought maybe there is a way to define it separately and access the gui objects from myfunc!

Comment: Looks like you're confusing static functions (old C-style notion of a compile-unit-local objects) and static member functions (class members that do not require an object to be invoked). If you've declared your function as MainWindow's public member, it can be used anywhere, simply include mainwindow.h and call it as MainWindow::func_sqrt(). If you simply put it in mainwindow.cpp as top-level static function, well that instant you've made it invisible for other compilation units. Either case, please compile a Minimal etc. example as yours is not sufficient.

Comment: I have declared the function under public slots of MainWindow as:
static void myfunc();
And if I change it to void, my code does not work anymore. It has to do with the SDK of a camera I'm working with.
From myfun(), I want to show a buffer image into a label that I have created in the gui, when I define myfunc() in the mainwindow.cpp file, I can have it as void but on the other hand, I cannot access the gui objects(that is what I have asked here). Second option would be to declare it in mainwindow.h as static void, but then I am not able to call another non-static function from myfunc().